# Is UK vaccine rollout really a Brexit benefit?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

I heard multiple times from different UK government officials that the UK did really good with Covid-19 vaccine rollout because the UK left the EU.

Is this true?
What EU policy/law would have forced the UK to do that differently?

Like in this one [Boris Johnson on fast vaccine rollout](https://youtu.be/A3eq5QGAg0k)

Comment: You can improve by adding sources.

Comment: I assume this is referring to the fact that EU member states cooperated with each other to prevent richer countries outbidding poorer countries. The UK not being an EU member state would not have been bound by that agreement and thus been able to outbid the EU and get access to more doses earlier. This is what happened with respirators in the US during early days of the pandemic, for example, where the states got into a bidding frenzy, the manufacturers jacked up the prices, and only richer states could afford them.

Comment: @JamesK added a link. I am sure there many others, but this is what basically all UK government officials say

Comment: @JörgWMittag But that was an opt-in scheme, not required for all EU members. If it had been mandatory then of course the UK would have had to join in, since 2020 was during the transition period when it was still following EU rules.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiple sources say it's not true.

https://fullfact.org/health/coronavirus-vaccine-brexit/
https://www.channel4.com/news/factcheck/factcheck-brexit-did-not-speed-up-uk-vaccine-authorisation

The crux of it is that under EU rules there would have been nothing stopping the UK doing what it did.

Comment: Please provide some of the information from the sources in your answer.

Comment: My understanding of the "Brexit benefit" was not so muct that vaccines were approced faster, but that they were rolled out to the people faster.

Comment: I'd also note that tons of EU rules were ignored during the pandemic via the "emergency" excuse, such as shutting down borders for no good reason. The UK could've done whatever it wanted in practice by claiming an "emergency".

Comment: @JoeW it's hard to provide evidence of something not existing.

Comment: @SimonB how would being an EU member have slowed down the roll out?

Comment: All I am asking is to take the information from the links you provided and place that information in your answer so that people don’t need to go to a different site to get an understanding of your answer

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Trilarion's answer, if we take "number of COVID deaths" as the primary metric, we can build the following chart between March 20th 2021 (when [half of the UK got their first jab](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2021/mar/20/uk-covid-vaccine-milestone-as-more-than-half-of-adults-have-had-first-dose)) and December 31st 2021. The chart shows a comparison of the UK vs the EU, adjusted per-capita.

The UK starts out with 2,249 deaths/1m and ends with 2,627 (increase of 16%)

The EU starts out with 1,313 deaths/1m and ends with 2,015 (increase of 53%)

So on that metric alone, the UK clearly did a better job than the EU. They accomplished this by going for "first doses first", approving Astrazeneca quickly, prepurchasing vaccine doses and having a very efficient campaign for convincing people over the age of 65 to get vaccinated. How much of this is due to being outside the EU is hard to say, as EU members routinely ignored EU regulations that year under the excuse of an "emergency", so I doubt the UK would've been stopped from executing the exact same plan without Brexit.

[image]

Comment: If we were to use that metric (number of deaths/pop), shouldn't the chart start at the beginning of the vaccination campaign, or maybe even at the begin of any governmental responses to adress the epidemic, rather than when half of the people UK had already received their first injection ?

Comment: @Evargalo no, because UK's pre-vaccination stats are not the question here

Comment: Still choosing 1st March as starting point is quite a bit of cherry picking. The UK had a huge wave before. Just seeing that the green curve is way above the blue curve might be seen as the UK had a huge failure before. Even before the vaccination they were at a level that wasn't reached by the EU after the vaccination. Just take a longer time period and then maybe mark the region you want to show. Because between December 20 and March 21 there was a huge wave in the UK. People died in waves from Covid, not constantly, so time limits matter.

Comment: @Trilarion the question is **strictly** about the vaccination policy, not about any other policies. You may ask a separate question about overall policy but this is not the question here.

Comment: I understand. Still I think you do cherry picking. Your conclusion would only hold if all other policies didn't change during that time and if there wouldn't be waves, but all other policies did change and there were waves. I'm not really convinced. Especially since you start right after a huge wave. Maybe it was just some overshooting in the other direction. Doesn't it bother you that your result depends so much on the chosen time frame? Could it be just coincidence? And if not speaking of a huge success when the situation is worse sounds a bit wrong.

Comment: @Trilarion I wanted to add an answer to counter-balance the claims in your answer. If you remove the deaths section from your answer, I'm happy to remove my answer.

Comment: Let's keep the answers. In the comments here I said enough.

Comment: @JonathanReez : Even if *the question is strictly about the vaccination policy*, I am sure you will agree that said policy didn't start *when half of the UK got their first jab*, but earlier, when the first people in the UK got their first jab ?

Comment: @Evargalo nope, we want to compare outcomes after the vaccinations were well underway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the UK could roll out vaccines to its citizens ahead of any EU-wide scheme.  [BBC News article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/explainers-56286235).

The EU tried to implement an EU-wide vaccination policy.  But it was so slow that individual countries ended up overriding it, and running their own vaccine programmes.

Meanwhile, the UK had been stockpiling vaccines even before they had been approved.  That meant that the vaccination programme could start as soon as the first vaccines were approved.

Comment: As the very article you link states, the EU scheme was optional. The UK could have simply done its own thing anyway, even without Brexit.

Comment: "individual countries ended up overriding it, and running their own vaccine programmes.", so the UK could have overridden it from the start and run its own program if it wanted, meaning this policy wouldn't have forced the UK to do things differently.

Answer (score 1):

> I heard multiple times from different UK government officials that the UK did really good with Covid-19 vaccine rollout because the UK left the EU.

Ultimately the UK had a headstart in the vaccine rollout, it's health agency approved the vaccine a few weeks faster (either simply working faster or just taking greater risks) and the deals with producers were better (especially the Astra-Zeneca one that was produced in Britain). However this vaccine was not so effective and the Biontech one that was produced in the EU did catch up quite nicely in production rates after a relatively short time.

Here you see the administration rates of first doses for large EU countries and the UK. The UK led from Dec. '20 to March '21, from April '21 the EU countries caught up. In August '21 Italy and France overtook Britain in first dose administration rates, indicating that by then the availability of vaccines was not a limiting factor anymore.

[image]

I'd say that both were actually incredible success stories. Having a vaccine ready and in mass production within one year is mind blowing. The UK could act independently and a bit faster, but that only resulted in three months headstart in this case. The EU wasn't so much worse and with UK inside the EU one could have expected some averaging because the EU in the end agreed on a common procurement scheme. Some EU citizen would have gotten more Astra-Zeneca earlier, some UK citizens a bit later. One advantage of the common procurement of vaccines was that nobody in the EU felt left behind.

By the way this is only one side of the story. Just look at the number of Covid-related deaths. Here is the cumulative number of deaths. One would need to divide this by the total population in order to get rates, but roughly the order of populations is Italy 60 Mill, France 65 Mill, UK 69 Mill, Germany 84 Mill, so kind of close. One can see that Covid was especially deadly during the vaccination period in the UK and even though more people were vaccinated in the UK during a certain time window, still the cumulative number of deaths grew faster (indicated by the widening gap between UK and the other countries). This indicates that the Corona vaccination rate was not the only factor determining the fatality of the illness. There were also lockdowns, face mask mandates, virus variants, ...

[image]

Of course that doesn't mean that I want to argue that increased Covid deaths were due to Brexit. There are simply too many factors involved and who knows what was the reason for the incredibly strong Covid death wave in Britain in Winter 20/21.

Comment: The astra zeneca vaccine was perfectly effective against hospitalization which is the only stat that matters. And I don’t quite understand why the death stats are particularly relevant unless you exclude the pre-vaccination period and adjust the numbers per capita.

Comment: I'd say roughly half a year advantage in the midst of pandemic is not insignificant by any measure, even if both are "success stories"...

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't understand why the hospitalization rate should be the only relevant number. If anything I would rather say that indeed the death rate is the most important thing. You don't want to die, going to hospital is bad but not as bad. I agree that numbers should be normalized but I couldn't do it easily.

Comment: @Zeus It's not half a year advance but rather three months (just shift the curves horizontally until they overlap) and it wasn't the same vaccine, so difficult to compare. My conclusion is that both were incredible success stories. On the other hand there are many other factors determining how well you do in a pandemic. Vaccination is only one of them.